# NSMutableArray and NSArray in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Initially I declared my array as:

```
var wrongAnswersArray: NSArray? = []
wrongAnswerLabel.isHidden = (wrongAnswersArray?.count)! <= 0 ? true:false
```

and my app worked fine. Later, I needed to modify the array so I declared it as mutable but I couldn't use the same statement for getting the count. XCode suggested to modified the statement in the following manner:

```
var wrongAnswersArray: NSMutableArray? = []
wrongAnswerLabel.isHidden = (wrongAnswersArray!).count <= 0 ? true:false
```

This compiles but fails at run time

1) Why couldn't we use the same statement? Why do NSArray and NSMutableArray behave differently?

2) Any way to solve this run time error?

Any documentation related to this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[String]` like `swift-array` & make it `let` for constants & `var` for mutable(variable)

```
var wrongAnswersArray: [String] = []
wrongAnswerLabel.isHidden = (wrongAnswersArray.count) <= 0 ? true:false
```

Further you can get help with https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Thanks!! It made the entire code simpler. Earlier I was using '?' everywhere.  I am new to swift. I will follow the documentation you sent.

Comment: This answer is not so "Swifty", and is unnecessarily verbose. You should use my "Swiftier" and more reactive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694853/1311272

Comment: A couple of notes: ternaries containing `? true : false` do not need to exist (just use the condition instead), and why would the array have fewer than zero elements (use `wrongAnswersArray.isEmpty` or similar instead)?

Answer (score 1):

Why hassel with `array.count <= 0 ? true : false`? And why `<=` even? Can an array have a *negative* length? You should just do this instead:

```
// start empty
var wrongAnswers = [String]()
... // app might append wrong answers to the array

// Later check:
wrongAnswersLabel.isHidden = wrongAnswers.isEmpty // done!
```

**Even better:**
Or you could "react" to changes to the array, by using Swift "property observer", e.g. "willSet":

```
// start empty
var wrongAnswers: [String] = [] {
    willSet {
        // Using `willSet` instead of `didSet` allows for use of implicitly declared variable `newValue`
        // which is good since it makes refactoring simpler, not having to refer to the name
        // of this variable (`wrongAnswers`) which we might want to change in the future
        wrongAnswersLabel.isHidden = newValue.isEmpty
    }
}
```